# csrf_meta_tags and form_for generate invalid base64 on Heroku

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-6

I am using ruby 2.7.1 and rails 6.0.3.4 and hitting the following error whenever I try to call `csrf_meta_tags` or `form_for`

```
2021-02-01T07:25:10.058892+00:00 app[web.1]: [9c50e00c-9868-45dc-89d8-1ec8f42d56ab] ActionView::Template::Error (invalid base64):
2021-02-01T07:25:10.058893+00:00 app[web.1]: [9c50e00c-9868-45dc-89d8-1ec8f42d56ab]     1: <h2>Log in</h2>
2021-02-01T07:25:10.058894+00:00 app[web.1]: [9c50e00c-9868-45dc-89d8-1ec8f42d56ab]     2:
2021-02-01T07:25:10.058895+00:00 app[web.1]: [9c50e00c-9868-45dc-89d8-1ec8f42d56ab]     3: <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
2021-02-01T07:25:10.058895+00:00 app[web.1]: [9c50e00c-9868-45dc-89d8-1ec8f42d56ab]     4:   <div class="field">
2021-02-01T07:25:10.058896+00:00 app[web.1]: [9c50e00c-9868-45dc-89d8-1ec8f42d56ab]     5:     <%= f.label :email %><br />
2021-02-01T07:25:10.058898+00:00 app[web.1]: [9c50e00c-9868-45dc-89d8-1ec8f42d56ab]     6:     <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "email" %>
2021-02-01T07:25:10.058899+00:00 app[web.1]: [9c50e00c-9868-45dc-89d8-1ec8f42d56ab]
2021-02-01T07:25:10.058899+00:00 app[web.1]: [9c50e00c-9868-45dc-89d8-1ec8f42d56ab] app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb:3
```

I only get this error in production when deployed to Heroku.  In development, the authenticity token is generated without error, but for some reason on Heroku the above error ie produced.  Any idea what could be going on here?

I have tried to narrow down what line(s) are causing the issue, and I got as far as `form_authenticity_token` and `masked_authenticity_token` but I so far have not been able to trace which lines are the issue.

Some other possibly relevant versions:

```
Gemfile.lock
------------
webpacker (4.3.0)

yarn.lock
---------
@rails/webpacker@4.3.0
```

I've tried simply omitting the `csrf_meta_tags` but then I still hit the error on forms as shown above.  I can't find any references to others with the same issue, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: ruby 2.6.5 rails 6.0.3 getting the same error in production (not heroku). Started at about 7:00 GMT.

Comment: What is your 'webpacker' version?

Comment: @MichałCzapko I updated the description.  Both development and production appear to be using webpacker 4.3.0 according to the Gemfile.lock and yarn.lock files.

Comment: I don't use webpacker.

Comment: I had a similar issue and it was automagically fixed when I redeployed the application without the CSRF tags and once again with the same code that didn't work earlier.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On our servers this problem was caused by downgrading Rails from 6.1 to 6.0.3.

Firstly we tried to upgrade rails from 6.0.3 to 6.1, but missed some needed changes for migration to be successful and had to revert back to 6.0.3. However, during the time our app ran on Rails 6.1 many user requests were served and new csrf tokens were generated. The thing is, Rails 6.1 has different algorithm for csrf token generation and when we reverted back to Rails 6.0.3, tokens that were generated by Rails 6.1 could not be validated.

To alleviate the problem and avoid showing errors to users we decorated csrf generation function to catch aforementioned errors and reset session so that tokens compatible with Rails 6.0.3 can be generated.

```
def rescued_csrf_meta_tags
  csrf_meta_tags
rescue ArgumentError
  request.reset_session
  csrf_meta_tags
end
```

Additional server info:

- Ubuntu 16.04
- Ruby 2.6.5

EDIT: As @cecomp64 wrote in the comment, another solution is to clear browser cache. Obviously, this won't be easy to implement if your app has many users.

Comment: This is exactly the issue!  I also contacted Heroku support, and they recommended simply clearing the cache and cookies in my browser, and that also worked.  I understand that if you have a mature app, you don't want to advise all your users to do this, but for me, clearing the cache was enough.  Could you please add the "clear-your-cache" workaround and I will accept the answer?

Comment: The cache clear works great. Where do you put the decorator?

Comment: Just as a side note, clearing the cache only was not enough for me. I had to clear the cookies as well. And that was a problem I was seeing actually on Chrome only.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the **csrf token** generation between Rails 5 and 6 is incompatible  (different algorithm) and as such, you need a function to generate a new encryption to handle the aforementioned compatibility errors.

Your **application_controller.rb**:

```
protect_from_forgery with: :exception
```

Your **application.html.erb** in the *head* tag:

```
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

Your **application_helper.rb** or **csrf_helper.rb**:

```
def csrf_meta_tags
  if defined?(protect_against_forgery?) && protect_against_forgery?
    [
      tag("meta", name: "csrf-param", content: request_forgery_protection_token),
      tag("meta", name: "csrf-token", content: form_authenticity_token)
    ].join("\n").html_safe
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/5273

```
# config/initializers/sidekiq.rb
require 'sidekiq/web'
Sidekiq::Web::CsrfProtection.define_method(:decode_token) do  |token|
  Base64.urlsafe_decode64(token)
end
Sidekiq::Web::CsrfProtection.define_method(:encode_token) do |token|
  Base64.urlsafe_encode64(token)
end
```